# Why don't max pooling layers break CNNs performance in solving regression problems?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

When I think about a max pooling layer I think about it detecting features that are anywhere in their receptive field, but agnostic as to the location.

It seems this spatial invariance properly of max pooling should mean it loses information about the exact location of features in the original image.

How then, can a CNN with several layers of max pooling accurately predict the bounding boxes of objects in an image? A quick Google shows many examples of CNNs with max pooling being recommended for bounding box regression problems.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Because your assumption that it'll loose information about the exact location is wrong. Max pooling does not dilute the location of the maximum pixel - instead consider it as a way of downsizing. Max pooling is just a way to reduce dimensionality of the problem such that your problem fits into device memory. A nice side property is that it pools the strongest acitvations from your feature map.

In the case of bbox prediction it also reduces the number of proposed regions for bboxes. Which later in a non-maximum surpression step would kill all redundant proposed bbox locations.